# PHP array print statement

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
        if(is_file($userName.".txt")) {
            $userDetails = explode(',', file_get_contents($userName.".txt"));
            print($userDetails[0]);
            if ($password == $userDetails[0]) {
                print('Correct login');
            } else {
                print('Incorrect login');
            }
        }
```

And I have the following file: Simon.txt with the following contents: simonpassword,4,1
If the $userName is 'Simon', when the code is run, how come 4 is printed out instead of simonpassword at the line: print($userDetails[0])?

Comment: Are you kidding? print($userDetails[1]);

Comment: Can you give the output of `print_r($userDetails);`

Comment: Sandeep: Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 2 ) - Why would that be... the text file definitly has the following text: simonpassword,4,1

Comment: what should it has to print.. tell me... according to array it is showing correct

Comment: r u using correct loop without same variable name declared previously?

Comment: Then show the result of `echo file_get_contents($userName.".txt");`

Comment: @user1400702 According to your print_r the simonpassword isn't showing in the array, can you just do a `echo(file_get_contents($userName.".txt"));` to see what that outputs through PHP.

Comment: I would verify the contents of your file, it seems the value you want isn't shown in the txt file

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$userName = "Simon";
$password = "simonpassword";
if(is_file($userName.".txt")) {
        $userDetails = explode(',', file_get_contents($userName.".txt"));
        print($userDetails[0]);
        if ($password == $userDetails[0]) {
            print('Correct login');
        } else {
            print('Incorrect login');
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is Simon.txt

```
simonpassword,4,1
```

And it works.